# What is the best strategy for keeping an android and iphone version of the same app

Tags: iphone, android, frameworks, mobile, ios-frameworks

I'm must build the same application for android and iphone.
I tryed rhodes, that is great, but some native ui features are missing...

I would like to know, is there a strategy, sdk, framework, or something for building native applications for android and iphone that somehow reduce the rework?
Or any suggestion of other framework, like rhodes...

Thanks

Comment: Put the two developers' desks side-by-side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a multiplatform framework for developing iPhone / Android applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953/is-there-a-multiplatform-framework-for-developing-iphone-android-applications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appcelerator Titanium

http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/

Comment: I tryed phonegap and Titanium, Titanium was the closest to what I was looking for. But when in 1 hour of native android development, I did the job of days in titanium, I changed directions and started 2 native apps.

Answer (score 5):

Phone Gap is the place for you. You should have a look at this http://www.phonegap.com/about

Answer (score 0):

Documentation, Documentation, Documentation!
Have a well written PDR and stick to it. 
there is another approach which is to use a tool that generates both simultaneously like: [phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/) or [corona SDK](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/).

Answer (score 0):

Design for some level of resolution independence. Try to code as much as you appropriately can in HTML rather than native controls. And wrap common API calls so you have 1 method to change rather than 100 different calls all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [monotouch](http://monotouch.net/) and [monodroid](http://mono-android.net/).

You may also want to see [Reusing Monotouch code in Monodroid app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670898/reusing-monotouch-code-in-monodroid-app)