# MonoDroid, MonoTouch common UI

Tags: c#, android, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I remember seeing a promising framework that let developers share the UI code of applications developed for MonoDroid and MonoTouch some time ago. Can't find it now, anyone knows its name?

Links to any frameworks attempting to achieve the same would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Is [Monocross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670898/reusing-monotouch-code-in-monodroid-app) what you are looking for?
Or [Monogame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) if you are going the XNA route?

Comment: The framework I'm talking about is a commercial product. It requires another subscription beside MonoTouch and MonoDroid. Monocross doesn't actually let you share the whole UI code right? That framework does, at least claimed to do so. Monogame actually lets (or going to let) you share everything, so thanks for mentioning that, but the framework I'm looking for is for general applications. I guess it could be done with Monogame, but would be a lot of work...

Answer (score 4):

You can also try Mvvmcross. I think it is branched from monocross but uses mvvm instead of mvc.