# Vici CoolStorage Portability: Monotouch, MonoDroid and Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, xamarin.ios, cross-platform, xamarin.android, vici

Is cross-platformness a good reason to use Vici CoolStorage?

Ideally you'd want to write data model once and use it in MonoTouch, MonoDroid and Windows Phone versions of the same app. In that case is Vici CS the best bet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have much experience with other ORMs, so I can't compare CoolStorage with other options.

I can tell you, though, that the code you write for your CoolStorage data layer will be 100% re-usable over the 3 platforms. Simply write a separate data layer library and include it in all 3 solutions.

Vici CoolStorage isn't complex to use, so you can easily try it out in a few hours. No steep learning curve. Just create matching data classes for your tables, define relations and start CRUDding :)

Any questions? Just use StackExchange or the support forum mentioned on [the support page](http://viciproject.com/wiki/support).

Comment: Haven't come across any other ORM which covers all MT, MD and WP. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: You can use SQLite across all 3, along with the sqlite-net ORM. Check out this post from Xamarin for more info http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/02/24/mwc_2012/

Comment: Thanks Greg. Is it possible for you to contrast the two as that will be very helpful. Is there an extra step before WP7 can be used with SQLite.NET?